# Does React warn of additional props that a component wasn't expecting?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

If I pass the prop `bar` to the component below, will React throw a warning/error?

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  ...
}

MyComponent.PropTypes = {
  foo: PropType.string,
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it only warns you when you pass a prop defined in `propTypes` that does not have the expected type.

If you want to be warned about this, you can use the [custom Airbnb implementation](https://github.com/airbnb/prop-types) of the `prop-types` package that includes a validator `forbidExtraProps`.

You also have a typo in your example code. The proptypes object on your component needs to start with a lower-case `p` to make it work:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  foo: PropTypes.string,
};
```